# ActiveRecord How to figure out NULL fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

How I may filter NULL fields

```
no_repeat = Events.where(:repeat => NULL)
```

NULL word doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
no_repeat = Events.where("repeat IS NULL")

no_repeat = Events.where("repeat = ?", nil)

no_repeat = Events.where(:repeat => nil)
no_repeat = Events.where(repeat: nil)
```

Comment: No problem, just a small note; your model should be named in the singular form `Event`.

Comment: Also question how I may select all fields? Something like user_events = Event.where(:user_id => user ? user : '*')